# Pandas: How do I "merge" the contents of 2 rows of alternating NaNs without adding extra columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where some of the columns either have data in them or NaN:

```
rows_dict = {'category': {305: 'Seasonings, Condiments, Toppings & Sauces',
                          536: 'Seasonings, Condiments, Toppings & Sauces',
                          627: 'Commercial Snacks'},
             'histamine_level': {305: pd.np.nan, 536: pd.np.nan,
                                 627: pd.np.nan},
             'food_name': {305: 'Peppermint', 536: 'Peppermint',
                           627: 'Peppermint flavored candy'},
             'oxalate_level': {305: 'Low', 536: pd.np.nan, 627: pd.np.nan},
             'salicylate_level': {305: pd.np.nan, 536: 'Very High',
                                  627: 'High'}}
pd.DataFrame(rows_dict)
```

[image: PreDataFrame]
So, I am trying to "merge" the rows that show this characteristic. For this I wrote a function that tries to exploit the OR property:

```
def merge_2_rows(df, left_index, right_index):
    row_dict = {}
    columns_list = df.columns
    for column_name in columns_list:
        row_dict[column_name] = df.loc[left_index,
                                       column_name] or df.loc[right_index, column_name]
    match_series = (df.index.isin([left_index, right_index]))
    df = df[~match_series]
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([row_dict], columns=columns_list), ignore_index=True)

    return df
```

But when I run `merge_2_rows(df=a_copy_of_the_above_df, left_index=305, right_index=536)`, I get this:

[image: PostDataFrame]

If the first index contains a NaN, the OR statement drops out and doesn't examine the second index. So this doesn't work. I've looked at `pd.merge` and there probably is a `Series` function that does this, but I can't find it. How do I merge the contents of two rows of of alternating NaNs without adding extra columns?

Comment: perhaps `combine_first` but I need sample data to be sure. Sharing images is usually not encouraged around here

Comment: Is the addition of a dictionary of the data good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a hint from @Yuca, this change in `merge_2_rows` is simpler and actually works:

```
def merge_2_rows(df, left_index, right_index):
    df.loc[left_index] = df.loc[left_index].combine_first(df.loc[right_index])
    match_series = (df.index == right_index)
    df = df[~match_series]

    return df
```

[image: CorrectDatFrame]